# PHP system() - return status is always -1

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    $cmd = system("wget http://la-lg.hostus.us/500MB.test",$r);
    echo $r;
?>
```

It is success and i can see new 500MB.test in my dir，but why return'-1'?

Comment: it returning 1 on my system

Comment: Is the file identical or just some bytes and the name as wget did create due to your request locally? Depending on the wget version it might be a  "1 Generic error code". Does it work on your systems shell? If it finishes, you might check with `$?` for the return code ... happy hacking! I read you hyphens as hyphens and not as minus ;-)

Comment: Thx,Linux or windows?My system is centos

Comment: i tested it on windows 7 ultimate+ linux (ubuntu)

Comment: thx,maybe some problem on my setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm purely guessing about this, but I think you get a -1 because wget returns immediately because it works asynchronously. At that stage the status is simply not known. You should check `$cmd` to see if the command was executed sucessfully. See:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm

It says: "This allows you to start a retrieval and disconnect from the system, letting Wget finish the work.".

You could test this theory, by checking how long `system()` takes to execute. You probably cannot download 500MB in less than 1 second.

Also check the date of the downloaded file carefully.

Comment: Thx,i can run it on my windows servers.May be some problem aboit  asynchronously.How can i fix it?

Comment: As far as I know an explicit `&` (ampersand) is needed at the end of a command to run that command in the background. You don't have that. That why I asked you to test whether or not `wget` does run in the background, or not. You have not reported back on that. So I currently have no suggestions to fix it. Information is key in a proper diagnosis of a problem.